# Graph Theory Proof:Number of paths from to v to v'

Tags: graph-theory

Theorem: The number of paths from v to v' of length k in G is $(A^{k})_{v,v'}$.

Formulate and prove a path counting result in the spirit of above theorem for directed graphs.

I am not sure what they are trying to ask and have no clue.

Comment: Well, how much DO you know?  Are you familiar with graph, path, directed vs. undirected, nodes / vertices, adjacency matrix?

Comment: Yes, I am. I just started an hour ago and know all these terms.

Comment: The above result is for undirected graph, they are probably asking for a similar result for the directed graph. That is, if $G$ is directed graph then the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^k (G)$ is the number of directed paths of length $k$ from $i$ to $j$.

Comment: Then for i->j should be $(A^{k})_{i,j}$.

Comment: Yes. If the graph is undirected, then $(A^k)_{i,j}$ gives us the number of paths from $i$ to $j$ (that is the same from $j$ to $i$).  If the graph is  directed, then $(A^k)_{i,j}$ gives us the number of directed paths from $i$ to $j$ (that is different   from  the number of directed paths from  $j$ to $i$).

Comment: Just curious : It can be zero also right? from j ->i but that is not the case in undirected

Comment: @max Yes that's right. $(A^k)_{i,j}$ and $(A^k)_{j,i}$ can both be zero in the directed graph even if there is a path from $i$ to $j$ of lenght $k$ (but of course the path in this case is not formed of  directed edges)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37710/discussion-between-max-and-m-badaoui).